Why does removing from a dictionary while iterating over it, work perfectly fine?
I have read in a few places that you cannot remove from a collection while iterating over it.
But I can do exactly this with a dictionary, and it works perfectly fine.
// no error
foreach (var item in myDict)
{
    myDict.Remove(item.Key);
}

// no error
foreach (var key in myDict.Keys)
{
    myDict.Remove(key);
}

var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// expected error
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    myList.Remove(item);
}


This is covered in the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> docs:

.NET Core 3.0+ only: The only mutating methods which do not invalidate enumerators are Remove and Clear.

And from Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Remove/Clear :

.NET Core 3.0+ only: this mutating method may be safely called without invalidating active enumerators on the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> instance. This does not imply thread safety.

See also:

Allow Dictionary<K,V>.Remove during enumeration @github

